# Confused about 'close' in UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've read a lot of threads and tutorials about UILocalNotifications and I'm confused about the 'close' button. For example, this one is linked to a lot: [HERE](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html)

When I use a UILocalNotification set for every 5 seconds (as a test) and I tap the 'close' button, the notifications stop. Everything I've read said that's not supposed to happen. They all say a notification will continue until the user opens the app and does something (whatever you need them to do).

(The behavior I want is a notification until the app is opened and I can't seem to get it)

What's going on?
Is this and iOS version-specific behavior?

Comment: You must be mistaken. It's **not possible** to schedule a `UILocalNotification` that repeats every 5 seconds. It could repeat every **1** second, or every minute, or every hour, or every day, or every week, and so on. But **not** every 5 seconds.

Comment: @yuji Yes, I think I misunderstood how the notification works. I was under the impression that 'firedate' was an interval, not a single point. I've seen other posts now that basically state you have to create multiple notifications calculated to fall within NScalendar constants. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can schedule up to 64 local notifications.
There is no reason why you couldn't schedule a notification every 5 seconds, using an increasing NSTimeInterval.
What you need to ensure though is that the application cancels all local notifcations yet to fire as soon as the app opens. Otherwise the remaining notifications you schedules would still be primed to fire.

In your above statement, I think you mis understand the close action. This does not act like a snooze button on the alarm. A local notification will only fire once, even when dismissed.

The only way around it is to schedule multiple, similiar, notifications as I mentioned above, or to adda repeat interval. Repeat intervals are not customisable though and may not fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, I think I misunderstood how the notification works. I was under the impression that 'firedate' was an interval, not a single point. I've seen other posts now that basically state you have to create multiple notifications calculated to fall within NScalendar constants. Thanks.

Comment: glad it helped. some of the code in one of my open source projects may be of use for scheduling. https://github.com/Burnsoft/Settings-Swipe

Answer (score 1):

You cannot schedule a notification to repeat every five seconds. The `repeatInterval` on `UILocalNotification` is of type `NSCalendarUnit`, which must be one of the values listed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSEraCalendarUnit), and there is no "unit" for five seconds.

Since `NSCalendarUnit`is typedef'd to `NSUInteger`, you will not get a compiler error when assigned an integer to `repeatInterval`, however you will not see the expected results (as you are experiencing).